# Apriori model not showing obvious associations

Tags: r, apriori

I am doing Apriori model for the first time. I have created a test dataset as attached. Clearly there are strong associations like {A,C} -> {K}, {A,C,G} -> {K} etc. But the Apriori model gives me 0 rules with LHS populated.

[image]

The code that I am using is:

```
file6 <- read.transactions("C:/.../Test.csv", sep=',')
rules1 <- apriori(file6, parameter = list(sup = 0.001, conf = 0.005, minlen = 2))
rules1
```

The result is:

```
set of 0 rules
```

I think I am missing something. Please help me find what the issue is.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the data is not read correctly. Try:

```
file6 <- read.transactions("C:/.../Test.csv", sep=',')
summary(file6)
itemLabels(file6)
```

I suspect that the items are not separated correctly.